# Unexpected directory layout after moving project into new directory

Tags: go, gopath

I was working on a Go project in a directory that was not in my GOPATH. I was using relative imports.

I am trying to move the project into my GOPATH so I can stop using relative imports, but I keep getting `unexpected directory layout` errors.

I've checked the Go docs "how to write Go code" but I still can't see what the problem is.

The GOPATH is currently

`/Users/M/go`

The GOROOT is currently

`/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.1/libexec`

The project is currently located in

`/Users/M/go/src/github.com/code/project`

I am trying to make the following imports:

```
package aws_service

import (
    "github.com/project/server/DB"
)
```

Where `"github.com/project/server/DB"` is another package I created within my project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is hard to tell from your description what is `project` and what is `code` and if `project` in `github.com/code/project` and `github.com/project/server/DB` is same.

When using `GOPATH` your projects need to be checked out in predefined [GitHub Layout](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GithubCodeLayout) which is `$GOPATH/src/github.com/<username|orgname>/<repo>/packages...`. Try to fix your example to be less ambiguous.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59015137/1349518

Comment: Use Go modules. Read How to Write Go Code and show your go.mod.